# Two condition must be true in SQL

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have two tables.

1. Student
2. Student Interest

Table: Student

```
Id | Student Name
------------------
1  | John
2  | Alice
```

Table: Student Interest

```
Id | SId | Interest
------------------
1  | 1   | Mathematics
2  | 1   | Science
1  | 2   | Environment
2  | 2   | English
2  | 2   | Mathematics
```

This two table is connected with the foreign key in "student Interest" Table

Now **I want the name of students who has interest in both "Mathematics" and "science"**

I tried this

```
Select s.Name from Student s
Inner Join StudentInterest si
ON
s.Id = si.SId
Where si.Interest IN ('Mathematics' , 'Science')
```

But it shows both student because both the student have interest in 'Mathematics'
The result should be only 1 student named "John"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by the student you can select only those having both interests like this

```
Select s.Name 
from Student s
Inner Join StudentInterest si ON s.Id = si.SId
Where si.Interest IN ('Mathematics' , 'Science')
group by s.Name
having count(distinct si.Interest) = 2
```

or

```
Select s.Name 
from Student s
Inner Join StudentInterest si ON s.Id = si.SId
group by s.Name
having sum(case when si.Interest = 'Mathematics' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when si.Interest = 'Science' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```